# inquiry about OpenGL32.dll version's issue using EGL 1.4

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, egl, wgl

I’m a C++ application developer on Windows system. I’m developing an application using EGL 1.4 and OpenGL ES 2.0.

In a certain kind of a OpenGL32.DLL version, I found that a PVR error message occurred. The versions of OpenGL32.DLL that cause this problem are 6.3.9600.16384 on Win8.1 and 4.0.1379.1. And the message says :

```
PVR Message

PVR: VFrame attempted to use one of these functions:
PVR: wglChoosePixelFormatARB
PVR: but they are not present on you machine.

Ignore?
```

This message appeared when I call eglChooseConfig() or eglGetConfigs() functions in EGL API to get system configs.

I think this problem occurred because OpenGL32.dll versions mentioned above don’t support wglChoosePixelFormatARB() function.

Most of versions that I tested worked well. List of working version is :

```
5.2.3790.3959
6.1.7600.16385
6.3.9600.16384(1000kb)
10.0.10130.0
```

And list of not working version is :

```
4.0.1379.1
5.1.2600.1280
5.1.2600.5512
6.3.9600.16384 (720kb)
```

To solve this problem, I want to include this dll file in my product for a commercial use. I want to know that distributing a working version of OpenGL32.dll is possible. And can you know me the list of OpenGL32.dll version without this error and license information about OpenGL32.dll?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not about the `opengl32.dll` (in fact its inner working hasn't changed since Windows NT-4 some 19 years ago). Your system is simply missing a graphics driver with full OpenGL support:

The graphics drivers that are installed by default on Windows (and Windows Update) have only a very limited, stripped down OpenGL support (in fact they hardly support GPU acceleration). To get proper, full OpenGL support you **must** download the driver package for your GPU from the GPU vendor's website and install it manually.

Using Windows standard, automatic driver installation and Windows Update will not give you proper OpenGL support.